# Sending SMS from iphone application to user

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4, ios4

i am creating an application where user will find the deal and if he want to receive the deal detail by sms or email.
  how user will get sms and mail from my application without using web service if any sample code is available then please help me.
  Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For mail you can check out this: MFMailComposeViewController and its delegate MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate.

Documentation here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html

For sending SMS, MFMessageComposeViewController.

Documentation here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: thanks to all for the reply ,but this is not i m looking for. in the above posts the sms/mail can be send from the device only. but i need the sms to be send from the app.

Comment: please find the detail of this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209432/sending-detail-information-of-a-deal-to-user-from-iphone-app

Comment: It looks to me like this is what you're asking.. "Sending SMS from iphone application to user". This is exactly what those two controls do. They bring up a message composer, where you fill in the number and send him an SMS. This is all done from within your iOS application. You never launch either the native mail or the native messaging app. Those two are prebuilt controllers ready to be integrated in your app.

Comment: Hi Vlad in the above posts sms will go from the device.but i need they should go from the client side to user of the app. where sender is client. thanks in advance

Comment: @Vlad He is asking for a way for the app to send an SMS to the user *of the app*, not another user. Unfortunately I don't think it's possible because Apple forces the use of their text message UI.

Answer (score 0):

Apple provides `MFMessageComposeViewController` which can be used to send SMS too. This article should solve your problem - [How to Send an SMS Progammatically in iOS](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/core-services/how-to-send-an-sms-progammatically.html)

Comment: Hi Srikar Thanks for reply but i was asking that i want to send sms from my application to user( like verification code ) that example is sending sms from iphone....